# Next Textbox on Enter with 2 group boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, groupbox

I have two group boxes, in the first group box I have 3 textboxes and in the second group box I have 1 textbox. I added this code:

```
private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Enter))
    {
        SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

But enter only works in the first group box and jumps over the button and skips the 2nd group box.
What should i do?

Comment: @Smartis i did that, it still jumps over the second group box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) mentioned:

> The SelectNextControl method activates **the next control in the tab order** if the control's Selectable style bit is set to true in ControlStyles, it is contained in another control, and all its parent controls are both visible and enabled.

You can find your Controls (Textbox's) **tab order number** on the Property `TabIndex` in the Designer.

[image: Properties Window in the Designer]

Comment: @SMG there is a bug in the designer where you have to reset the values of index to work properly.